# AttributeError on Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm stuck with (I think) a dummy error on Django that I can't find where it's the fault.

On "catalog/models.py" I have (it connects to a MySQL database):

```
from django.db import models

class Application(models.Model):
    nameApp = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tarification = models.ForeignKey(Tarification)
```

Then, I'm using *django-tables2* ([Doc to fill tables](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/table-data.html)) to make tables on Django, so on my *tables.py* I have:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from catalog.models import AppCost, Application, Tarification


class BillTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        appName = Application.nameApp
        userApp = AppCost.userApp
        tarifName = Tarification.nameTarif
        tarifCost = Tarification.cost
        startTime = AppCost.startTime
        finishTime = AppCost.finishTime
        totalCost = AppCost.totalCost
        # add class="paleblue" to <table> tag
        attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}
```

And I get an error when I render my website:

```
type object 'Application' has no attribute 'nameApp'
```

On the line `appName = Application.nameApp` from *BillTable*

But, looking at "Database" window on *Pycharm* I see the table schema and it's:

- catalog_application

  - id
  - tarification_id
  - nameApp
  - other stuff

And looking with MySQL Workbench the schema looks the same. So, why I'm getting this error?

Regards.

Comment: You should consider following PEP-8, and try to look at [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id36)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel Roseman mentioned above, the code you might looking for is below, it does not need a new model:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from catalog.models import AppCost, Application, Tarification

class AppCostTable(tables.Table):
    userApp = tables.Column()
    startTime = tables.Column()
    finishTime = tables.Column()
    totalCost = tables.Column()

    class Meta:
        model = AppCost

class ApplicationTable(tables.Table):
    appName = tables.Column(accessor='nameApp')
    class Meta:
        model = Application

class TarificationTable(tables.Table):
    tarifName = tables.Column(accessor='nameTarif')
    tarifCost = tables.Column(accessor='cost')
    class Meta:
        model = Tarification


class BillTable(AppCostTable, ApplicationTable, TarificationTable, tables.Table):
    pass
```

If you do not mind to have another model, then inside your **catalog.models** you can add a new Bill model:

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    application = models.ForeignKey('Application')
    appcost = models.ForeignKey('AppCost')
    tarification = models.ForeignKey('Tarification')
```

In your table file:

```
from catalog.models import Bill

class BillTable(tables.Table):
    appName = tables.Column(accessor='application.nameApp')
    tarifName = tables.Column(accessor='tarification.nameTarif')
    tarifCost = tables.Column(accessor='tarification.cost')
    userApp = tables.Column(accessor='appcost.userApp')
    startTime = tables.Column(accessor='appcost.startTime')
    finishTime = tables.Column(accessor='appcost.finishTime')
    totalCost = tables.Column(accessor='appcost.totalCost')


    class Meta:
        model = Bill
```

Comment: Hi, I know but I'm looking for a way of make a table with different fields from multiple tables in a database or with "django_tables2" can't be done? You know something with I can do it?

Comment: Hi, @Aker666. You might want to look at the link at the end of my comment. It talks about how to use multiple tables in a single view. However, the document has not that much detail. Let me know if you have more questions. https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/generic-mixins.html#multiple-tables-using-multipleobjectmixin

Comment: It works and it's what I was looking. I've used the second method (add Bill model inside catalog,model). Thanks for help me understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You're very confused about how to use django-tables. You need to specify one model in the Meta class, then just the `fields` attribute to add a list of fields from that model, as strings, to display. You can't just specify fields from three arbitrary models.

Comment: So how I can make a table with different fields from multiple tables in a database?